# Wrap items only if they are not already within a certain element

Tags: jquery, dom, jquery-selectors

jquery dom jquery-selectors simple issue, but I cannot nail it. I am crating a mega menu by manipulating a simple  list element.

My menu structure looks something like this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Something</a>
        <ul>
            <li>
                <a href="#">Some Sub Menu Item</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

On hover I have a simple rule: Find all **second level** `<li>` elements and wrap them in a  with class **.subMenuContainer**

Therefore, on hover, the above is transformed to this:

```
<ul>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Something</a>
        <ul>
            <div class="subMenuContainer">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Some Sub Menu Item</a>
                </li>
            </div>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Simply put, sub menu items are wrapped in a div so they can be positioned specifically.

This works fine on the first hover, but on the second hover the subMenuContainer  is wrapped yet again, so for 'X' amount of hovers I end up with 'X' amount of subMenuContainer  elements.

My jQuery rule for wrapping these

elements is as follows:

```
$('ul.someClass li').bind('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).find('ul').not(':contains(div.subMenuContainer)').find('li').wrapAll('<div class="subMenuContainer" />');
});
```

Surely by using the above code the items should only be wrapped in the div if there is not already a div with class .subMenuContainer inside the ?

Am I missing something?

Regards,
Simon

[EDIT] - See chosen answer below, the solution was simply to use **>** when searching for elements, eg: `$('ul > li')` which causes only `<li>` items that are direct children of the `<ul>` (and not in the div) to be found. Thank you.

Comment: By standards `ul` element should contain `li` child elements only.

Comment: What @VisioN said, you should change how you structure your `menu/html`.

Comment: @VisioN & jSang - I do not have control over the menu structure, it is a Wordpress menu that I am working on. It has already been established and I am working on top of someone elses work. I am well aware of the rules of the <ul> DOM element, but that was not the question in hand, I simply need to know if there's a flaw in my jQuery logic or if I am missing something.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happens because :contains is for usage with text, not elements.
Try this:

```
$(this).find('ul > li').wrapAll('<div class="subMenuContainer" />');
```

or

```
$(this).find('ul').children('li').wrapAll('<div class="subMenuContainer" />');
```

Only li's that are immediate childs of ul are wrapped now.

Comment: This was indeed the quickest and most simplest solution. I am now  wiser than I was 2 hours ago as I never knew that the '>' character denoted items only immediately children of the parent! Ha, learn something new every day! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `.one()` instead of `hover()` or `bind()`.

```
$('ul.someClass li').one('mouseover', function(){
    $(this).find('ul').find('li').wrapAll('<div class="subMenuContainer" />');
});
```

Comment: The actual code uses hoverIntent plugin, I just wrote the hover code to demonstrate the basic intention of the menu.

Comment: Given that I cannot use .one() in my situation because the menu is already build using the hoverIntent plugin I have not been able to test it, but surely with the above the user would be able to see the hover menu on first rollover of each <li> item and then never again thereafter?